# Buttons added programmatically not responding correctly

Tags: java, android, button, android-relativelayout, onclicklistener

i am adding buttons programmatically to my layout with dividerVertical views between each button.

you know when you click a button, the button becomes darker for a moment to show it has been pressed. as i am adding more buttons under each other, only the button at the bottom will be showed as pressed. even when i am pressing one of the other buttons, the bottom button still shows as it were the one to be pressed.

in the OnClickListener the correct button that i clicked will however be shown.

as an example: when pressing "firstperson", the "thirdperson" will be showed as pressed (it gets darker for a moment). but in the onclicklistener the firstpersons text will be retrieved. anyone know how i can solve this problem?

my mainLayoutfile where the buttons are being made:

```
public class MainLayout 
{
    public static Button getButtonWithImage(int id, Context context,Drawable imageView, Drawable theme, int below, int color, String born, String name)
    {
         LayoutParams paramsImage = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         if(below != -1)  paramsImage.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, below);

         Button b = new Button(context);
         b.setId(id);
         b.setLayoutParams(paramsImage);
         b.setText(name + "\n" + born);

         Rect t = imageView.getBounds();
         imageView.setBounds( 0, 0, 96, 96 );

         b.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, imageView,null);
         b.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
         b.setBackground(theme);
         b.setTextColor(color);

         return b;
    }
    public static View layingView(int id, int below, Drawable attribute, Context context )
    {
        LayoutParams paramsViewThird = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 3);
        paramsViewThird.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, below);

        View v3 = new View(context);
        v3.setId(id);
        v3.setBackground(attribute);
        v3.setLayoutParams(paramsViewThird);
        return v3;
    }
}
```

my method that makes the layout:

```
   public void visAlleKunder(RelativeLayout rel)
    {
        int[] attrsV = new int[] {android.R.attr.dividerVertical};
        TypedArray td = obtainStyledAttributes(attrsV);
        Drawable attribute = td.getDrawable(0); 
        td.recycle(); 

        int[] attrs = new int[] {android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground};
        TypedArray ta = obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
        Drawable drawableFromTheme = ta.getDrawable(0); 
        ta.recycle();

        int color = (getResources().getColor(R.color.black));

        Button button = MainLayout.getButtonWithImage(01, getApplicationContext(),  (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_edit)), drawableFromTheme, -1, color, "06.11.1995", "firstperson");
        View dividerView = MainLayout.layingView(02, 01, attribute, getApplicationContext());
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        rel.addView(button);
        rel.addView(dividerView);

        Button button2 = MainLayout.getButtonWithImage(11, getApplicationContext(),  (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_edit)), drawableFromTheme, 02, color, "02.02.1987", "secondperson");
        View dividerView2 = MainLayout.layingView(12, 11, attribute, getApplicationContext());
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);

        rel.addView(button2);
        rel.addView(dividerView2);

        Button button3 = MainLayout.getButtonWithImage(31, getApplicationContext(),  (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_edit)), drawableFromTheme, 12, color, "06.02.1980", "thirdperson");
        View dividerView3 = MainLayout.layingView(32, 31, attribute, getApplicationContext());
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);

        rel.addView(button3);
        rel.addView(dividerView3);
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View view) 
{
    Button b = (Button) view;
    String tekst = b.getText().toString();
    System.out.println("Buttons Choosen text: " + tekst);       
}
```

how the layout looks like: [image: picture of the layout]

This became a very long post, but i will appreciate any answer to what i might be doing wrong :)

Comment: Where is your `OnClickListener` code?

Comment: hey, i have added it after visAlleKunder :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice how your setting the listener for button2 instead button3:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(this);
```

change it to

```
button3.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: hey, thx for answering :). i have changed it but it dosen't solve the problem. when i click on the first button, the third button will become darker as it was that button i clicked. but the first button will still be the one responding in onclicklistener.

Comment: Because they share the same Drawable. Instante a new one for each button. Use a diferent `drawableFromTheme` for each button.

Comment: hey, thx :) changing instante drawableFromTheme for each button fixed it, can't believe i spent 14 hours on this :) appreciate it :)